# .NET MVC C# - Add class to current menu item

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a Helper to add a class for the current menu item

```
public static string CurrentItem(this HtmlHelper helper, string action, string controller)
    {
        string classValue = "";

        string currentController = helper.ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("controller").RawValue.ToString();
        string currentAction = helper.ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("action").RawValue.ToString();

        if (currentController == controller && currentAction == action)
        {
            classValue = "wb-navcurr";
        }

        return classValue;
    }
```

But it's not working in my Partial because I already have classes set up...

```
@Html.ActionLink("Search", "Search", "Home", null, new { @class = "list-group-item wb-sec-h3 h3" })
```

When I add my Helper class it just displays as is in HTML

```
@Html.ActionLink("Search", "Search", "Home", null, new { @class = "list-group-item wb-sec-h3 h3 Html.CurrentItem(\"Search\", \"Home\")" })
```

So how do ADD a class to those I already have?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a string:

```
"list-group-item wb-sec-h3 h3 Html.CurrentItem(\"Search\", \"Home\")"
```

It may contain what looks like code to a human, but .NET isn't going to execute that code.  It's just a string.

In order to execute code, you have to remove it from the string and concatenate its result to the literal string.  Which might look something like this:

```
"list-group-item wb-sec-h3 h3 " + Html.CurrentItem("Search", "Home")
```

Comment: Of course! It's going to be one of those days I think. Thanks for the help!